# Find specific character in string property from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I need to filter a list of objects according to whether a specific property (String type) contains the character 'S' (or 'N') in position 19.

I have this in C#:

```
IQueryable<Tabla5> lstTipoGasto = objServiceClient.ListaTabla5(int.Parse(number)).AsQueryable();
Tabla5 objTipoGasto = new Tabla5();
objTipoGasto.NombreNom5 = "Seleccione..";
objTipoGasto.CodigoNom5 = -1;
objTipoGasto.TextNom5 = "...";
List<Tabla5> lst = lstTipoGasto.ToList();
lst.Add(objTipoGasto);
lstTipoGasto = lst.AsQueryable();

var lista = lstTipoGasto.AsEnumerable().ToList().Where(x => x.AgregaTabl.Contains("S"))
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        x.CodigoNom5, 
        x.NombreNom5, 
        x.TextNom5, 
        x.AgregaTabl 
    }).OrderBy(x => x.CodigoNom5).ToList();

uddlTipoGasto.DataSource = lista;            
uddlTipoGasto.DisplayMember = "NombreNom5";
uddlTipoGasto.ValueMember = "CodigoNom5";
uddlTipoGasto.ValueMember = "TextNom5";
```

I get an exception. Any ideas why?

Comment: What is the exception message? Also your code doesn't check the character at position 19 right now.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're checking position 19, you're just using `Contains()`..

Comment: The exception is (in spanish):
Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: The original query:

`var lista = lstTipoGasto.AsEnumerable().ToList().Where(x => x.AgregaTabl.Substring(18, 1).Equals("S")).Select(x => new { x.CodigoNom5, x.NombreNom5, x.TextNom5, x.AgregaTabl }).OrderBy(x => x.CodigoNom5).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
var lista = lstTipoGasto.AsEnumerable()
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.AgregaTabl.Length > 18 && 
           (x.AgregaTabl[18] == 'S' || x.AgregaTabl[18] == 'N'))
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        x.CodigoNom5, 
        x.NombreNom5, 
        x.TextNom5, 
        x.AgregaTabl 
    }).OrderBy(x => x.CodigoNom5).ToList();
```

Instead of checking if `x.AgregaTabl.Contains("S")`, you check that `x.AgregaTabl.Length > 18` so we know that it has at least 19 characters, then we check `(x.AgregaTabl[18] == 'S' || x.AgregaTabl[18] == 'N')` to see if the 19th character is 'S' or 'N' (Note: x.AgregaTabl[18] accesses the 19th character due to 0-based indices).